# How to implement a Reverse Proxy in Sitecore?

Tags: redirect

I have a Sitecore URL (wwww.abc.com/home/legend). I want to call a different URL when this URL is called.
Suppose, I have

- URL A - wwww.abc.com/home/legend (Sitecore One)
- URL B - www.xyz.com/hello.php (hosted in different CMS)

If I call URL A, then the content from URL B will be displayed but the URL in the browser will not change. I tried with IIS rewrite but it is changing the URL also, so that's not what I want. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Is this question the same as https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/3645/how-to-setup-a-reverse-proxy-with-sitecore? If yes, I would close this one.

Comment: @TamásTárnok No, that question is more of a redirection one. Here I asked about how to retain the same URL while content changes.

Comment: thw answer what I gave their does not overwrite the url but loads the content from an external domain

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIS Rewrite cannot do that by itself, you will have to install the Application Request Routing (ARR) IIS Extension for that, you can download it [here](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/application-request-routing). When you have that installed you can put in something like this:

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="Reverse Proxy" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="^home/legend$" />
            <action type="Rewrite" url="www.xyz.com/hello.php" />
        </rule>        
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Comment: I think in this case the URL will change, but the question was "the content from URL B will be displayed but the URL in the browser will not change"...

Comment: The URL should not change if the reverse proxy is setup correctly, more details about this can be found here https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-v2-and-application-request-routing